# How to impelement method in Android instead callback?

Tags: java, android, oop

for example

```
binding.more.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(context,view);
            popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup, popupMenu.getMenu());
            popupMenu.show();
            popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(item -> {
                switch (item.getItemId()){
                    case R.id.delete:
                        delete(position,view);
                        Toast.makeText(context, "File Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;

                }
                return true;
            });

        });
```

i want to change the code to

```
            binding.more.setOnClickListener(setPopupMenu(position,view));
```

and setPopupMenu(); will be like

```
    private View.OnClickListener setPopupMenu(int position) {
    PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(context,v);
    popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup, popupMenu.getMenu());
    popupMenu.show();
    popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(item -> {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.delete:
                delete(position,v);
                Toast.makeText(context, "File Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

        }
        return true;
    });

}
```

i tried to make the method but i don't know how to get the view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do something like pass view just like position as a parameter in  **setPopupMenu(int position, View view)**  method like be

```
private void setPopupMenu(int position, View v) {
PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(context,v);
popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup, popupMenu.getMenu());
popupMenu.show();
popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(item -> {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.delete:
            delete(position,v);
            Toast.makeText(context, "File Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

    }
    return true;
  });
}
```

> And call the method using binding with help of lambda like  below:

```
 //calling setOnClickListener using lambda function
 binding.more.setOnClickListener {view -> setPopupMenu(position, view)};
```

Comment: hey, can you upvote this? it would be helpful to me too.